# Установка Zend framework на  Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: framework, php, zend-framework, ubuntu, mvc

Доброго времени суток, знатоки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне поставить, корректно, вручную зенд, чтоб работали zend_tools. Имеется:

```
Ubuntu 11.04, apache2+php5.3.5+mysql.
```

Что я сделал:

1. По руководству с сайта `http://zend-framework.ru/getting-started/` - скачал архив фреймворка версии 1.11.10
2. Распаковал его в `/usr/local/zendf/`
3. В терминале под root набрал `gedit .bashrc`
4. Дописал в конец файла алиас - `alias zf=/usr/local/zendf/bin/zf.sh`
5. Сохранил, закрыл файл

Пишу в терминале `zf show version`, на что получаю ответ:

> Программа 'zf' на данный момент не установлена.  Вы можете установить её, выполнив: sudo apt-get install zend-framework-bin

Если ставлю зенд через aptitude install, все работает прекрасно, но хочется разобраться в этой ситуации. Подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: Есть еще у кого то какие то соображения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему! Может кому пригодится:

- Скачиваем дистрибутив [отсюда](http://framework.zend.com/download/latest). Желательно качать tar.gz, хотя это не играет особой роли.
- В териминале набираем `sudo bash`, логинемся под root'ом.
- Копируем закачанный дистрибутив:  `cp /home/username/downloads/ /usr/local/`
- Заходим в папку `cd /usr/local/`, и разархивируем архив - `tar -xzvf ZendFramework-1.11.10.tar.gz`
- Переименовываем папку `mv ZendFramework-1.11.10 ZendFramework`
- Устанавливаем права на папку: 
  `chmod 0755 ZendFramework
  chmod -R 0755 ZendFramework/*`
- Создаем ссылку на zend tool: `ln -s /usr/local/ZendFramework/bin/zf.sh /usr/bin/zf`
- После этого можно тестировать Zend Tool - набираем `zf show version` и если все сделали правильно - на экране появится версия зенда.
- Теперь добавляем zf в include_path php: 
  `gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
  Находим строки:

  ;UNIX: ";/path1:/path2";
  ;include_path = ".:/usr/share/php";
- Раскомментируем include_path и добавляем:

  include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/local/ZendFramework/library"
- Сохраняем, закрываем. Перезапускаем апач и готово. теперь можно создавать проекты и пользоваться всеми прелестями Zend Tool.

При обновлении зенда - качаем новый дистрибутив, заменяем содержимое папки и пользуемся самой последней версией. Всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте следующее:

- в чьём .bashrc вы добавили алиас
- выполнялся ли .bashrc после этого? достаточно запустить новый терминал, чтобы запустился новый баш, который выполнил бы .bashrc

Comment: пробовал gedit /home/username/.bashrc, щас попробую с новым терминалом. Под рутом надо пробовать?

Comment: нет, не работает с новым терминалом ни под обычным юзером, ни под рутом